# Force small image in WhatsApp link preview for IPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp, social-media

So when I create the OG tags for my website I have 2 image tags, the first for other social media and the second that is meant to only be used for whatsapp.

I intentionally make the whatsapp one smaller so that it can appear more compact with the image positioned to the left of all the content, as appose to displaying big at the top of the content.

This has worked until recently, but then IPhone changed it to use the bigger image (the one used for other social media platforms), which is a problem for my client (its a branding thing).

Is there a way to force it to use the compact layout in the whatsapp link preview?

EDIT: I say IPhone, but a better term to use would probably be iOS.